# How to convert View::make to email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-4.2

In my controller I return this view which I am trying to convert to an email shown below. The view works fine but my email is not sending. I'm not sure why.

```
 public function emailRegistrationConfirmation()
 {

    $user = Auth::user();
    $errors = Session::get('error');
    $warning = Session::get('warning');
    $info = Session::get('info');
    $success = Session::get('success');

    $return_mail = Config::get('mail.from.address');

    $attendeesIds = $user->attendees()->get()->lists('id');

    $programs = ScheduledProgram::whereHas('registeredAttendees', function($q) use ($attendeesIds){
                $q->whereIn('attendees.id', $attendeesIds);
              })->where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
                ->where('end_date',                '>=',  $today)
                ->get();


    $sent =  Mail::send('user/registration/show', compact( 'user','programs', 'programsProcessing', 'cart','errors', 'successes', 'info', 'warning'), function($message) use ($return_mail, $user)
    {

      $message->to($return_mail, 'Confirmations')
              ->subject('RECEIPT: ' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
    });

    return $sent?'sent':'not sent';

    /*OLD return View worked fine*/
    return View::make('user/registration/show', compact('user','programs', 'programsProcessing', 'cart'))
          ->withError($errors)
          ->withSuccess($success)
          ->withInfo($info)
          ->withWarning($warning);
    }
```

My page returns `not sent`. I guess this means the Mail::send failed.
PhpDebugBar shows in the email tab

```
Message-ID: &lt;f6d6143403eda66af66ada902039c149@dev.registration.innisfillibrary.ca&gt;
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2018 16:43:27 -0400
Subject: RECEIPT: pwang1 wang
From: automailer &lt;registration@innisfillibrary.ca&gt;
To: Confirmations &lt;registration@innisfillibrary.ca&gt;
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: Have you verified that your mail settings are correct? Are you certain the target email address is valid? Can you access that mail account to verify it is sent or not? Have you checked your storage/logs/laravel.log for errors or warnings? Maybe this helps as startup troublethooting: http://laraveldaily.com/test-email-artisan-tinker/

Comment: @RobBiermann I followed your suggestions and it turns out my return_email had been disabled by the SysAdmin. I hardcoded my own email and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Send HTML email like this in Laravel and `emails.register` means path will be `emails/register.blade.php`

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.register'], [
      'url' => url("set-password/some-verify-token"),
      'email' => $request->input('email')
   ], function ($mail) use($email) {
      $mail->from(env('SUPPORT_EMAIL'), env('APP_NAME'));
      $mail->to($email);
      $mail->subject('welcome');
});
```

Return file path is wrong so change it `user/registration/show` to `user.registration.show` and file path will be `user/registration/show.blade.php`

```
return View::make('user.registration.show', compact('user','programs', 'programsProcessing', 'cart'))
          ->withError($errors)
          ->withSuccess($success)
          ->withInfo($info)
          ->withWarning($warning);
    }
```